# Is a Rust-Oleum painted item safe for infants?

Tags: child-safety, spray-paint

I’m considering purchasing a custom made item for an infant that’s been painted with Rust-Oleum. Considering children like to put things in their mouth, could this paint be hazardous? I’ve read about VOCs but it seems those arise during painting, and the child would only receive the item once the paint is dried.

Comment: For custom made items, paint is the least of your concerns.  Testing for infant toys is *harsh* for a reason.

Comment: @Harper - Naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any paint recently manufactured in the US should be safe, with the exception of expensive specialty paints that you can't purchase in the home center. (i.e., antifouling paints) That being said, the rule of thumb for any finish is that it will take a month to cure even if it dries faster. After thirty days all of the resins should be converted to a stable, solid form.

You should still apply some common sense and supervision. Being generally safe is not the same as safe in every conceivable situation.